# Bad credentials when using ldap in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

I'm using Spring-Security and ldap for authentication.My frontend is Angular.

When i will test ldap authentication ,login page show

> Bad credentials

[image]

but my password and username is correct

please help me.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("CN={0}")
                .contextSource().url("ldap://dc.msv.net:389/dc=msv,dc=net")
                .managerDn("CN=automation,CN=Users,DC=msv,DC=net").managerPassword("Y@sin@72");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your are using Active Directory, so you have to use `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ldap-active-directory).

Comment: Assuming *"password and username is correct"* refers to the manager account used for ldap binding, and that your application use case is about authenticating actual users (not that technical account), and that the *"Bad credentials"* refers to one of this actual users - We need to know what does a generic user dn looks like, I mean a "user base" is probably missing behind `CN={0}` (eg.`CN={0},ou=Users`) in `auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("CN={0}")`. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56076765/2529954) for more info.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208404/spring-boot-ldap-authentication-always-get-bad-credentials/58821231#58821231

Answer (score 0):

Try this found for my:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RestController
public class AutentificacionLdap extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${config.url_ldap}")
    String url_ldap;
    @Value("${config.usuario_ldap}")
    String usuario_ldap;
    @Value("${config.password_ldap}")
    String password_ldap;
    @Value("${config.userSearchFilter}")
    String userSearchFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/datawatcher/").authenticated()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {

        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource()
                .url(url_ldap)
                .managerDn(usuario_ldap)
                .managerPassword(password_ldap)
                .and()
                .userSearchFilter(userSearchFilter);

    }

}
```

Use .httpBasic();

And put in application.properties (but if you want put in class)

```
 #Conectar y Autentificar con LDAP
config.url_ldap=ldap://localhost:3268/dc=javadev,dc=com
config.usuario_ldap=CN=userforConnect,CN=Users,DC=javadev,DC=com
config.password_ldap=password
config.userSearchFilter=CN={0}
```